# FreeNas Support Hareware And Software

Tags: motherboard, hard-disk, nas, processor

I need to setup FreeNas Server, So I follw this [freenas setup](http://www.shanekirk.com/2012/08/rolling-your-own-nas-with-freenas-part-two/)  and collect all the Hardware Details,

What They Used:

```
    Motherboard       BOXDQ45EK LGA 775
    Processor         Pentium E2160 processor
    Heatsink /fan     Fanner-420 heatsink/fan made by MassCool
    Ram               1 GB
    Power supply      400W Rosewill RD400-2-DB
    Hard Drive        1TB WD10EZRX
    Ups               CyberPower CP1000AVRLCD UPS
    Case              PC-Q11B from Lian Li
```

But, They used Some Older versions Hardware's, so I try to find out New One Based on our Older Requirement.

I collected Hardware:

```
    Motherboard       Intel BOXDP67BGB3 Socket 1155, Intel P67, CrossFireX & SLI, SATA3&USB3.0, A&GbE, ATX Motherboard 
    Processor         Intel Core i5-3570K Quad-Core Processor 3.4 GHz 4 Core LGA 1155 - BX80637I53570K 
    Ram               Kingston -1600MHZ_PC3 (4GB)
    Hard Drive        WD Black 1TB Performance Desktop Hard Disk Drive - 7200 RPM SATA 6 Gb/s 64MB Cache 3.5 Inch -                 WD1003FZEX 

    Power supply      Rosewill ATX 12V 750-Watt 80 PLUS BRONZE Certified Power Supply Hive-750 

    Heatsink /fan     MASSCOOL Fanner-420 Thermal Grease Cooling (FANNER-420) 

    Case             Lian-Li PC-Q11B Lian-Li Case PC-Q11B Mini Tower 1-0-2 FAN Aluminum USB 3.0 Black Mini-ITX
```

My Questions Are:

**1.** This Mother-Board(**Intel BOXDP67BGB3 Socket 1155, Intel P67, CrossFireX & SLI, SATA3&USB3.0, A&GbE, ATX Motherboard**) can Support  FreeBSD Linux?

Comment: You want to build a FreeNAS Server? Do you have any other requirements besides OS? Because all x86 and x86_64 systems support FreeBSD

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people use that board so it does work. I don't have any experience with it so I can't tell you how "plug-and-play" it is.

Your motherboard and your processor don't match though, so you will be unable to use that hardware together.

Comment: I searched about Hardware compatibility, it says, out mother board and processor Compactible.  See this link http://processormatch.intel.com/Processors/CompatibleProcessors?componentName=DP67BG

Comment: I used  `3rd Generation Intel® Core™ i5-3570K | Frequency: 3.40 GHz` processor

Comment: Your question states that it is an `Intel Core i5 6500 Skylake Quad-Core 3.2 GHz LGA 1151 Desktop Processor`

Comment: sorry,  i shouldn't see this. But i use `Intel Core i5-3570K Quad-Core Processor 3.4 GHz 4 Core LGA 1155 - BX80637I53570K `  processor. it support right?

Comment: @Rajkumar.E Yes, the P67 chipset on the motherboard supports that CPU. There should be no problems at all. Maybe you should edit the question.